# When Overriding a method, don't we override whole method? I tried to override java.awt.Container.paint

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, awt, overriding

I have a question about overriding. I thought that overriding a method is re-writing that method. But, while I was studying about how to override, I got a doubt. Suppose that I have written following code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;

import java.awt.Graphics;

public class guitryings_2 extends Applet{

    public void paint( Graphics g )
    {
        g.drawString("Hi", 25, 75);
        showStatus("Deneme");
    }

}
```

If the paint method includes only g.drawString("Hi",25,75); and showStatus doesn't exist, I get a message 'Applet Started'.

If override means re-writing whole the method, when I  write only g.drawStrings without, it means I didn't define any String that will be showed below. So shouldn't 'Applet Started' text disappear?

Comment: Add the `@Override` annotation above you method and try again.

Comment: @PiXel1225 What difference is that supposed to make? The annotation only gives a compile error if the method doesn't override anything.

Comment: @PiXel1225 where should I add?

Comment: @DenizhanSoydaş It doesn't change anything, I just mentioned that. User `@Override` annotations when you are overriding methods, just above the declaration of the method.

Comment: @Kayaman Exactly, first rule of overriding, make sure you're actually overriding something

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well I know that. But he *is* overriding `paint(Graphics g)`, so adding the annotation and trying again doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Kayaman Ensures at least one potential issue is ticked off the check list and saves us the hassle in the future ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Effectively, you are overriding `java.awt.Container.paint(Graphics g)` since neither `Applet` nor any class in the hierarchy up to `Container` provide their own implementation of `paint()`.

This is the method you are overriding (and, yes, methods are always overridden as a whole - you can not override part of a method only. The only thing you can do is to call the overridden method, like `super.paint(g)`).

However, `java.awt.Container.paint()` does not contain any Applet specific code, 
hence the message which you see (`Applet started`) is obviously printed by the Applet container - like the browser (which still has the main control over its status bar), or the Applet Viewer.

On a side remark, note that Applets are being deprecated and some browsers already decommissioned the required native APIs to support Applets at all.

Comment: so, is it eclipse? if i don't define a showStatus message, it defines the default message for me , right? @Andreas Fester

Comment: `java.awt.Container.paint(Graphics g)` actually (which does provide an implementation), but yeah.

Comment: so it's not about overriding as well ?